# Jquery fading text with loop

Tags: jquery, loops, fade

I am trying to make a div containing text fade out another div fade in then the original come bac then repeat or loop it so it is constantly repeating the 2 messages this is my code:

```
<div id="specialoffer">
  <div id="specialoffertext">Reduced rates over the <br />
    next few months</div>
  <div id="specialoffertext2" style="display:none;">Contact us today to <br />
    find out more</div></div>​

    var $body = $(document.body),
    cycle;

(cycle = function() {
        $('#specialoffertext')..delay(2000)fadeOut('slow');
        $('#specialoffertext2').delay(3000).fadeIn('slow');
        $('#specialoffertext2').delay(3500).fadeOut('slow');
        $('#specialoffertext').delay(5000).fadeIn('slow', cycle);

})();​
```

It worked fine when playing with it on jsfiddle and then soon as I uploaded it it does not work??

Comment: You should really proof read your code samples before posting them... Looks like you have some minor syntax errors that could be causing unexpected results.

Comment: You don't have loops there, and the body elements is used for...?

Answer (score 3):

Your code wouldn't run in jsfiddle as you have an extra dot here and you are missing another one

```
 $('#specialoffertext')..delay(2000)fadeOut('slow');
```

take it off and put it in the right place

```
 $('#specialoffertext').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```

And evrything should work

http://jsfiddle.net/kEGgC/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
(function foo() {
    $('#specialoffertext').toggle('slow', function() {
        $('#specialoffertext2').toggle('slow', foo);
    });
})();​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uvL3g/)

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle handles loading jQuery for you.  Did you perhaps forget to include the jQuery libraries?

Also you have (what looks like) JavaScript code outside of `<script>` tags.

You should place your code inside some `<script>` tags and also utilize jQuery's `document.ready` callback.

```
$(function(){
  // your code goes here
});
```

You also have syntactic problems with this line -

```
$('#specialoffertext')..delay(2000)fadeOut('slow');
```

There is an erronious double period before `delay` and you are missing a period before `fadeOut`.